# Office printer Canon C3200 jamming?

Tags: printer

Our office printer is a big Canon Image Runner C3200, and it keeps jamming, people in the office keep complaining about it.

I've been told it has something to do with the teeth that grab the paper.

Anybody know anything about this printer?  I don't know too much about large office printers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likley a roller that picks up the paper that needs replacement or there is an small piece of something in the path.  Have it looked at by a qualified service tech.

We have a similar unit and someone decided to "fix" the problem.  The damage they did was way more than having it done right by a tech.

---